# Heroku error when trying to launch foreman

Tags: python, heroku, ubuntu-12.04, worker, foreman

I am trying desperately to get the Heroku to just run as the directions say for my evaluation and I am not haveing any luck.

I have an acer with ubuntu 14.04.

error I am getting:(I am new so I know what nothing means)

```
foreman start web
16:34:04 web.1  | started with pid 15434
16:34:04 web.1  | [2015-06-19 16:34:04 +0000] [15434] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
16:34:04 web.1  | [2015-06-19 16:34:04 +0000] [15434] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (15434)
16:34:04 web.1  | [2015-06-19 16:34:04 +0000] [15434] [INFO] Using worker: sync
16:34:04 web.1  | [2015-06-19 16:34:04 +0000] [15440] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15440
16:34:04 web.1  | [2015-06-19 16:34:04 +0000] [15440] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
16:34:04 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
16:34:04 web.1  |   File "/home/rodney/python-getting-started/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
16:34:04 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
16:34:04 web.1  |   File "/home/rodney/python-getting-started/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
16:34:04 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
16:34:04 web.1  |   File "/home/rodney/python-getting-started/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
16:34:04 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
16:34:04 web.1  |   File "/home/rodney/python-getting-started/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
16:34:04 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
16:34:04 web.1  |   File "/home/rodney/python-getting-started/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
16:34:04 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
16:34:04 web.1  |   File "/home/rodney/python-getting-started/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
16:34:04 web.1  |     __import__(module)
16:34:04 web.1  | ImportError: No module named gettingstarted.wsgi
16:34:04 web.1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
16:34:04 web.1  |   File "/home/rodney/python-getting-started/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
16:34:04 web.1  |     worker.init_process()
16:34:04 web.1  |   File "/home/rodney/python-getting-started/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 118, in init_process
16:34:04 web.1  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
16:34:04 web.1  |   File "/home/rodney/python-getting-started/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
16:34:04 web.1  |     self.callable = self.load()
16:34:04 web.1  |   File "/home/rodney/python-getting-started/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
16:34:04 web.1  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
16:34:04 web.1  |   File "/home/rodney/python-getting-started/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
16:34:04 web.1  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
16:34:04 web.1  |   File "/home/rodney/python-getting-started/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 355, in import_app
16:34:04 web.1  |     __import__(module)
16:34:04 web.1  | ImportError: No module named gettingstarted.wsgi
16:34:04 web.1  | [2015-06-19 16:34:04 +0000] [15440] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 15440)
16:34:04 web.1  | [2015-06-19 16:34:04 +0000] [15434] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
16:34:04 web.1  | [2015-06-19 16:34:04 +0000] [15434] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
16:34:04 web.1  | exited with code 3
16:34:04 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
(venv)rodney@rodney-Aspire-V5-571P:~/python-getting-started$
```

Comment: What is in your Procfile and do you actually have a subdirectory called 'gettingstarted' in the top of your project with a file called 'wsgi.py' in it.

Comment: Proc file contains "web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -"

Comment: But do you actually have a subdirectory called 'gettingstarted' in the top of your project with a file called 'wsgi.py' in it?